# Как сделать SuppressWarnings для всех использований метода?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

У меня имеется метод:

```
Session getSession(Player player);
```

Этот метод может вернуть объект класса `Session`, но так же может вернуть `null`. В документации этого метода объясняется, что и в каких случаях он возвращает.

Если использовать этот метод, тогда intellij idea будет показывать такой warning:
[image: warning]

Но intellij idea не понимает, что в данном контексте `null` не может быть по логике кода, но разработчик это знает и он не хочет делать проверку на `null`.

Конечно, я могу установить аннотацию `@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")`. Но она уберет warning только для данного использования метода `getSession`. Дело в том, что в 90% случаев этот метод не возвращает `null`, и разработчики об этом знают, по этому не хочется повсеместно ставить аннотацию `@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")`.

Как пометить метод `getSession`, чтобы во всем проекте у всех его использованиях пропал warning?

Comment: Session.getSession это ваш метод или библиотеки?

Comment: @Komdosh это мой

Comment: повестье аннотацию @Nonnull на геттер, Idea должна реагировать на неё

Comment: @Komdosh это можно, но ведь метод все таки может вернуть `null`, получается обман

Comment: Можно сделать метод getNonNullSession(player) в нужном классе, который будет вызывать getSession, и в случае если получил null выбрасывать ошибку

Comment: @ЕгорМалько оо, вы мне подсказали решение, правда без исключения. если перенести тело метода `getSession` в метод `getSession0`, который будет вызываться методом `getSession`, тогда intellij idea не будет делать warning. я ответом напишу это решение

Answer (score 0):

Если тело метода `getSession` вынести в метод `getSession0`, тогда intellij idea не будет делать warning.

Вот как это выглядит:

```
Session getSession(Player player) {
    return getSession0(player);
}

Session getSession0(Player player) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант использовать тип Integer вместо int, даже если выпадет null, NPE в данном участке кода не произойдет. Либо согласно чисто-писанию, назвать метод getIdorNull. По хорошем лучше отловить исключение, и на его место поставить какое нибудь кодовое значение. Прим: -1